how to auto convert time to timestamp
my backtesting code read UNIx timestamp, but time in the CSV file is in this format 2020-04-10 04:00:00,
it should be like this 1512045180000. what changes need to be done to be able to read it. I tried different ways but its hard for me.

def getEthereumData(start_date, end_date):
    print("Start reading ethereum data..")
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    data = pd.read_csv(path + "\\data\\BTCUSDT-1m-data.csv")
    data['DateTime'] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000) for ts in data["Timestamp"]]
    data = data.set_index('DateTime')
    data = data.dropna()
    data = data[parse(start_date): parse(end_date)]
    print("Reading complete")

    return data


it seems you already have timestamp in data["Timestamp"]. Why do you need to convert format 2020-04-10 04:00:00 to timestamp? If you get error message then show it in question (not in comments)

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

First you have to parse the string to a datetime, then you can get a timestamp.
Below a minimal code to reproduce it.
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# Parse the string
datetime_str = '2020-04-10 04:00:00'
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("Date = {}".format(datetime_obj))

# Get the timestamp
timestamp = int(datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
timestamp_ms = timestamp * 1000
print("Timestamp = {}".format(timestamp))
print("Timestamp ms = {}".format(timestamp_ms))

See datetime.datetime.timestamp and datetime.datetime.strptime

To convert the datetime format "2020-04-10 04:00:00" to a Unix timestamp format like "1512045180000" in Python, you can use the datetime module to parse the datetime string and then convert it to a Unix timestamp. Here's how you can do it in your case:
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def getEthereumData(start_date, end_date):
    print("Start reading ethereum data..")
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    data = pd.read_csv(path + "\\data\\BTCUSDT-1m-data.csv")
    
    # Convert datetime strings to Unix timestamps in milliseconds
    data['Timestamp'] = data['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: int(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp() * 1000))

    data = data.set_index('Timestamp')
    data = data.dropna()
    data = data[(data.index >= start_date) & (data.index <= end_date)]
    print("Reading complete")

    return data




from datetime import datetime

# Define your datetime string
date_str = "2020-04-10 04:00:00"

# Parse the datetime string
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Convert the datetime object to Unix timestamp (milliseconds)
unix_timestamp = int(datetime_obj.timestamp() * 1000)

# Print the Unix timestamp
print(unix_timestamp)


thank you I tried but I couldnt do it. maybe I have to change other parameters but I am beginner. thank you
